# How can I check independence over R in C2

Tags: linear-algebra

Very simple question which I'm not sure how to answer it.

Prove that: (Some of them maybe not be necessary right so I need to show an example why it is wrong)

1. $\{(3-2i,1+i),(2,1-5i)\}$ is linearly independent in Vector Space $C^2$ over $R$
2. $\{ix^2 +x -i, x^2-ix+1,x^2 -ix\}$ is linearly independent over C and over R

I tried in (1.) to put them in matrix like that:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3-2i & 2  \\
        1+i & 1-5i \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
and then $R_2 -> i * R_2$
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3-2i & 2  \\
        0 & i+5 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
And thus, they are linearly independent over C, but I don't know how to show (if possible) over R. and also, did I write that matrix correctly? and what about (2.) how can I show its linearly independence over R or over C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb {C}$ , linear independence over $\mathbb{C}$ implies linear independence over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Now I need to show (2.)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS : It is not very different from $1$